# getSupportFragmentManager() cannot resolve method

Tags: android, android-fragments

Below is my main Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //GETTING THE ERROR HERE
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Master mView = new Master();
                    return mView;
                case 1:
                    Device dView = new Device();
                    return dView;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Master";
                case 1:
                    return "Device";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting an error at the line saying `mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());` saying that cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager.

I changed the base class of MainActivity from `Activity` to `FragmentActivity` since `getSupportFragmentManager` is a method of `FragmentActivity` but is that Ok if I don't have a class that doesn't extend the `Activity` class? I am new to Android and not sure if it's ok to do that?

Answer (score 2):

> but is that Ok if I don't have a class that doesn't the main Activity class?

`FragmentActivity` extends `Activity`. Hence, you are extending the main `Activity` class, just indirectly.

Comment: Quick question. You always need one class that extends `Activity` in an Android project correct?

Comment: @Bobby: "I checked and for some reason found that it didn't" -- if you look at [the `FragmentActivity` JavaDocs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html), the third line starts with "`extends Activity`". "You always need one class that extends Activity in an Android project correct? " -- "always" is a strong word. :-) Usually, an Android app has one or more activities. There are a few scenarios where you might have none, but they are very uncommon (e.g., writing a plugin for some other app).

Answer (score 0):

Your class must extend `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity` to access `getSupportFragmentManager()` .